# Is there a way of performing arithmetic operations on entire Frame in Python datatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

This question is about the recent h2o datatable package. I want to replace pandas code with this library to enhance performance.

The question is simple: I need to divide/sum/multiply/substract an entire Frame or various selected columns by a number.

In pandas, to divide all the columns excluding the first by 3, one could write:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "C0": np.random.randn(10000), 
    "C1": np.random.randn(10000)
})
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:]/3
```

In the datatable package, one can do this just for one selected column:

```py
import datatable as dt
from datatable import f

df = dt.Frame(np.random.randn(1000000))
df[:, "C1"] = dt.Frame(np.random.randn(1000000))
for i in range(1,df.shape[1]): df[:,i] = df[:,f[i]/3]
```

By now, in Python 3.6 (I don't know about the 3.7 version), the *FrameProxy* f doesn't admit slices.
I'm just asking if there's a better way to perform this kind of Frame arithmetic operations than a loop, I haven't found it on the [Documentation](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-datatable.html).

**EDIT:**

Latest commit [#1962](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/pull/1962) has added a feature related to this question. If I'm able to run the latest source version, I'll add myself an answer including that new feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of January 2019, both the Python 3.6 and 3.7 versions of `datatable` installed via `pip` support slices with *f-expressions* and it is [documented](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/f-expressions.html#multi-column-selector). Thus, the solution is straightforward.

```py
import datatable as dt
from datatable import f
import numpy as np

# generate some data to test
df = dt.Frame(C0=np.random.randn(1000000),
              C1=np.random.randn(1000000))

df[:, 1:] = df[:, f[1:]/3]
```

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that `f`-symbol does not support slice expressions currently (which is an interesting idea btw, perhaps this could be added in the future?)

However, the right-hand side of the assignment can be a list of expressions, allowing you to write the following:

```
df = dt.Frame(C0=np.random.randn(1000000),
              C1=np.random.randn(1000000))

df[:, 1:] = [f[i]/3 for i in range(1, df.ncols)]
```

Comment: What a shame, I suppose it'll be added in the future. Anyways, f right-hand list comprehensions seem useful, thank you.